# SqlCommand CommandTimeout property

Tags: c#, asp.net, database-connection

i have developed a web application asp.net C#.

on a button click i am connecting to the database which takes long time to execute.
initially it use to timeout. now i increased the  commondtimeout property ,

```
cmd.CommandTimeout = 500;
```

basically it processing of paygroups.
time required depends on num of employess in that paygroup.

so my question is if 1 of paygroup requires less time to execute say 2 or 3 mins, will the connection sill be open for specified time in commandtimeout property?

if yes . can we estimate the processing time and set the time accordingly .

Comment: but why do you want to set lesser time? set the upper bound only

Comment: FYI, the language is named "C#", not "csharp".

Comment: CommandTimeout is an upper threshold - if the command completes in less time, any synchronous code will continue as soon as the command completes.

Comment: Please check new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why dont you try out something like this

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{
  //your codee to perform database operation
}
```

this will close your connection once your work get completed.

Comment: @kumarchaudhari - you can set the value there no issue in it but it remain for this scop only..

Answer (score 0):

1. In Order to let the Query execute completely, Set the `CommandTimeOut = 0`.
2. Why It is taking so much time? Your transaction should be quick enough to let other query execute in time.
3. `SQL Profiler` can help you optimize your database queries. I assume you are using SQL Server